# How to declare the driver (chrome/ie) globally which is used in both main and sub methods in cross Browser testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit

While automating cross browser test, I used the driver in both main and sub method. It is showing syntax error in the line "System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\chromedriver_win32"
Thanks

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    public class MyClass {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IO Exception {
    driver.findElement(By.id("aaa")).clear(); 
    -do-
    String B = new MyClass().gettext("eeee"); 
    }
    driver.quit();
    }
    public String getIframe(String id) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("ddd")).clear(); 
    -do-
    return A;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by modifying the code as below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class MyClass {
static Webdriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IO Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();    
driver.findElement(By.id("aaa")).clear(); 
-do-
String B = new MyClass().gettext("eeee"); 
}
driver.quit();
}
public String getIframe(String id) {
driver.findElement(By.id("ddd")).clear(); 
-do-
return A;
}
}
```

So Simple!!!